# how to find height of dynamic flex component used as a popup

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, flash-builder, flex4.5

I've created a custom component with several inline item renderers that I use as a tooltip.  The height of the component is unknown, as the data contents of the component are not known until runtime.

However, when displaying the tooltip, occasionally it extends beyond the boundaries of the flash application, thus, I'd like to be able to detect this occurrence and reposition the tip.

The problem is that the height and width of the component are, apparently, not available until after being rendered by the popup manager. (i.e. they are always 0)

But, I do not know any way of finding out when the popup is actually rendered and, therefore, the height/width values available.

I tried adding a resize event listener to the component, but it doesn't appear to work, though I most certainly could be doing something wrong since it seems to me that the resize event only gives you the "oldWidth" and "oldHeight" of the object, which, at first display, would be 0...and useless to me.

Any ideas about how to proceed?

-----Edit-----
I have a base class like this:

```
public class TTComponent extends Canvas
{
  var _parentC:UIComponent;
  var popped:Boolean = false;
  var timer:Timer;
  var _comp:UIComponent;

  public function set parentComponent(pC:UIComponent):void 
  {
    _parentC = pc;
    _parentC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mouseOut);
    _parentC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mouseOver);
  }
  public function mouseOver(evt:MouseEvent):void
  {
    if (_parentC != null)
    {
      timer = new Timer(150,1);
      _comp = this;
      timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, function( tevt:TimerEvent ):void 
      {
        this.move( somex, somey);
        if (popped != true)
        {
           PopUpManager.addPopUp(_comp, parentComponent );
           popped = true;
        });
        timer.start();
    }
  }

  public function mouseOut(evt:MouseEvent ):void
  {
    if ( timer )
    {
      timer.stop();
      timer = null;
    }
    //If we popped up, remove the popup
    if ( popped )
    {
      PopUpManager.removePopUp( _comp );
      popped = false;
      parentC .removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mouseOut);
      parentC .removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mouseOver);
    }
  }
}
```

Then, an extended renderer like this:

```
<c:TTComponent name="T" xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                          xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                          xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                          xmlns:c="components.*">
  <s:BorderContainer>
    ...about 30 labels grouped in various manners
    ...2 lists with inline item renderers
  </s:BorderContainer>
</c:TTComponent>
```

Now, the code is called like this:

```
var w = new TTComponent();
w.data = data;
win.parentComponent = this;
```

This will add listeners to the mouse over and mouse out events on the parent, whatever it is, and then show or hide the tooltip accordingly.

------Edit------

Using a portion of what a commenter below suggested, this is the solution I came up with:

Inside the TTComponent class:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import mx.binding.utils.ChangeWatcher;

private var heightWatcher:ChangeWatcher;


public function set parentComponent 
{
  ...
  heightWatcher = ChangeWatcher.watch(this,'height',onSizeChange);
}

public function onSizeChange(evt:Event):void
{
  if (this.height != 0)
  {
    ....calculate the new component coords
    this.move(newx, newy);
  }
}
```

Note that this additional code doesn't bind to any component variable, it just adds a watcher on the component property.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also try binding your width and height. If these are made bindable in your class, flex will automatically adjust your popup's width and height.

When using mxml for your binding, you can just do something like this

```
<mx:YourComponent height="{HeightOfYourTooltip}" width="{WidthOfYourTooltip}"></mx:YourComponent>
```

You can also add a eventListener that listens to the change event if you want to reposition you component, like so

```
<mx:YourComponent height="{HeightOfYourTooltip}" width="{WidthOfYourTooltip}" change="yourComponentResizeHandler()"></mx:YourComponent>
```

If you are using a programmed approach, you should should use the changewatcher. Below is shown how you can use that.

```
ChangeWatcher.watch(YourComponent, "width", repositionHandler);
ChangeWatcher.watch(YourComponent, "height", repositionHandler);
```

If you want to watch for other variables or properties to change, be sure to add the [Bindable]-tag above your variables in your class, like this

```
[Bindable]
var myVariable:SomeVariable;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not sure this approach would work, seeing as I don't set the height of my component--it is determined at runtime.  How would I bind a variable to the height without knowing what to initialize it to?

Comment: Binding updates automatically. If you provide some code on how you call your component exactly and how your component is built up, I can provide some more details on how to implement the binding.

Comment: Just a note for anyone reading, I did some research on the ChangeWatcher and you don't actually have to bind variables to use it.  Check the latest edit in the question for what I did to solve this problem.

Comment: You don't have to bind the height of your components because height is Bindable by default. If you would create your own custom variables, you do have to make these Bindable :) Glad you were able to solve the problem using the changewatcher.

Answer (score 0):

For displaying toolTip which controls you are using in itemRenderer? Text or Label?

Comment: It was a label.  Well, actually, it's a series of labels and 2 lists.  The reason why I don't know the height until runtime is because of the data inserted into the lists.

Comment: so u having 2 list which renderer lables. Is it? whoes height you want to find List or the height of individual labels?

Comment: Heyy Checkout this>> http://tutorials.jenkov.com/flex-components/component-basics.html

Comment: I have a complex renderer that contains about 25 labels and 2 lists of undetermined size all put inside a component.  I am looking for the height of the whole component.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Listen update complete Event of that component. May this Help you. :)

Comment: Was a good idea, but it didn't work.  The height still reports as 0 in that event handler.  Must be something weird with the way popupmanager handles stuff.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This might be messy, but on the pop up component, you could add an event listener after complete is fired, if the height or width `== 0` then you setTimeout() to a function after say 100ms until you get valid data.

Yes, I know it is a bit of a hack, but those will eventually report correctly measured values so it's not going to call that many times.

Just an idea if you are against a deadline or something like this isn't critical.  :)

Comment: Another idea would be to create one of each type on init and basically fill and show when appropriate rather than creating and destroying them as needed- might actually be same memory depending on how many types (because the way flash snatches up memory and only collects when needed) it and definitely less cpu.

Comment: Actually, having one of these resident in memory and shifting the data on demand would be much faster than creating it from scratch every time.  Would it automatically resize itself based on the new sizes of the lists?  Maybe invalidateSize() would do it?

Comment: Also, I like your idea, though I am trying to avoid adding a hack.  I've already just designated a "display" area and am showing the tip in the same location every time until I (or we :D) figure out a proper solution.

Comment: Just tried out keeping one tooltip in memory, works flawlessly and automatically resizes the component when you bind new data.  Great idea!

Comment: Its actually a much better solution, I've done it myself for tooltips / notes that appear.  Glad it worked out for you  :)